# Read XML ModuleName / Param of XML Node

Tags: xml, xslt

Given that piece of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<History ModuleName="Table structure tree">
<Release Date="12122001" Version="3.1" Title="Carrier A" Author="">
    <Item Type="">Test A</Item>
</Release>
<Release Date="13122001" Version="3.2" Title="Carrier B" Author="">
    <Item Type="">Test B</Item>
</Release>
<Release Date="14122001" Version="3.3" Title="Carrier C" Author="">
    <Item Type="">Test C</Item>
</Release>
</History>
```

How can I read the ModuleName out of the node "History"?
I have different kind of values here, and I want my XSL to display either the one Headline or another, depending on the value of the Module name.

e.g. if ModuleName starts with "Table structrue", the headline in the XSL should be "Fields". If the ModuleName is something else the headline should be "Releases".

How can this be done?

I am really new to XML/XSL, so my current code (which does not work at all, that why I ask here) looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="historyvalue" select="History"/>
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(starts-with($historyvalue, 'Table structure'))">
      <h3>Releases</h3>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <h3>Fields</h3>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you want is held in the `ModuleName` attribute in the `History` element, so the syntax is as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="historyvalue" select="History/@ModuleName"/>
```

Note that this assumes you are in a template matching `/` (the document node, which is the parent of the `History` element).

I would also consider reversing the logic in the `xsl:choose` to get rid of the `not`.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="historyvalue" select="History/@ModuleName"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with($historyvalue, 'Table structure')">
        <h3>Fields</h3>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <h3>Releases</h3>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You don't really need a variable in this case, you do away with that, and just change the `xsl:when` to this....

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(History/@ModuleName, 'Table structure')">
```

Alternatively, consider a templated approach, with the logic in template matches, rather than `xsl:choose`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="History[starts-with(History/@ModuleName, 'Table structure')]">
    <h3>Fields</h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="History">
    <h3>Releases</h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this example, the template matching History with the extra condition (`History[starts-with(History/@ModuleName, 'Table structure')]`) has a higher priority to the template that just matches `History`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, your solution was very well explained and helpful! Thank you for your time taken!